# Button not clickable after onFling()

Tags: java, android, layout, onclick, onfling

I want to be able to click and swipe on my `Buttons`. But once I implemented the `onFling` method, I am unable to click on the `Buttons`. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);

    GestureDetector gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);

    OnTouchListener onTL = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
            }
    };

    //the Buttons are in the swipeLayout
    swipeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_screen_bttns);

    swipeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });

    //setting OnTouchListener for all my Buttons
    for(Button b: button_list)
        b.setOnTouchListener(onTL);
}
```

Once I used this code I was able to `fling` through my `Buttons` but the `Click` functionality stopped. Does anybody know why this is?

The `Buttons` are in the `swipeLayout` so I made its OnTouchListener return false. I guess that is wrong. How do I make the `Buttons` clickable and swipeable?

Comment: You replace any and all touch functionality of buttons with just the one of `onTL`. If you remove the last two lines click event should handle correctly.

Comment: I removed the last two lines and now I am able to click but unable to swipe... please helpp

Comment: I also have a few linear layouts inside the main linear layout. And each of those linear layouts contains my buttons. Do I need to include them in the code?